# SSD object detection - Class score and bbox coordinates computing

Tags: image-processing, python, object-recognition

How does **SSD ( single shot multibox )object detection model** computes the the confidence score and the bounding box coordinates, referring to **SSD paper**, it said that this process is done with the aid of **small convolutional Kernels**. The kernels will output ***four real values (bbox offsets)*** and a **vector with class scores**. Can someone explain how this process is done with more clarification?

SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector available at:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "according to SSD paper": um, which paper *exactly*? Link to it!

Comment: Hello @marcus, I added the link of SSD paper.